# pip install from Azure DevOps Python Artifacts feed not working

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

When I attempt to install a package from our Azure DevOps Artifacts feed, I get the error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/company_Software/_packaging/PyPI/pypi/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement as-api (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for as-api
```

As using `pip install -vvv` potentially produces confidential information, I cannot provide the full log here. Please feel free to ask any specific questions about the log. In the meantime, I can see promising messages like:

```
Found index url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/company_Software/_packaging/PyPI/pypi/simple/
Getting credentials from keyring for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/company_Software/_packaging/PyPI/pypi/simple/
```

And some problematic messages?:

```
Status code 302 not in (200, 203, 300, 301)
Skipping link: not a file: ...
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'as-api': discarding no candidates
```

#### Reproduction details

```
virtualenv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install -U pip
pip install keyring artifacts-keyring
pip install as-api
```

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops) was used to produce a pipeline to publish the package and the suggested way of installing the package. My approach is now a mix of both option 1 and option 2. Note the use of a php.ini file to set `--index-url` and the `artifacts-keyring` package (installing with `--pre` does not make any difference to the version), so it really doesn't make any difference. However, I have tried both options separately, it doesn't spawn a browser, so it gives the same result.

**System details:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Python 2.7.17

```
pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ----------
artifacts-keyring 0.2.8rc0
certifi           2019.11.28
chardet           3.0.4
configparser      4.0.2
entrypoints       0.3
idna              2.8
keyring           18.0.1
pip               19.3.1
pywin32-ctypes    0.2.0
requests          2.22.0
setuptools        42.0.2
urllib3           1.25.7
wheel             0.33.6
```

Folder structure:

```
test
  |-- test.py
  |-- .venv
         |-- pip.ini
         |-- ... other virtualenv folders and files
```

pip.ini:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/company_Software/_packaging/PyPI/pypi/simple/
```

#### Further analysis

- Using a clean laptop actually works with the above reproduction details. Other computers in the company also have the same problem, so some of our set up is conflicting with the authentication.
- If we use a pipeline (see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/pip-authenticate?view=azure-devops)) to install the `as-api` package, it works, so I suspect this is an authentication problem, but it's not mentioned on any documentation.
- Using https://username:password@... does not give any authentication error, even with wrong username and password.
- Using the correct username but have symbols in the password triggers interactive mode to enter username and password. However, this gives this error: `WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/company_Software/_packaging/PyPI/pypi/simple/as-api/` Note that I am the owner of the Artifacts feed and the team has been added as the owner in the permission tab.

Comment: Looks like the bug in `pip`: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6179. Still open.

Comment: @phd Interesting find. I wonder if it's the same problem though because if I set up a pipeline on Azure which installs the same `as-api` package, it seems to work (see the final point in my post).

Comment: Perhaps Azure in the second case doesn't send back a redirect?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT That's actually the same as my approach, which I got from the same page. I just tried the exact same commands on the page again and it gives the same results. Adding `--pre` doesn't make any difference to the version, and using `--index-url` is the same as mine except pip won't search the https://pypi.org/simple index. Sorry for the confusion, I should've added more stuff that I've tried in the question. I will update that now.

Comment: Do you pass the login-in check like the pic in my answer? I tried the both two options and find in some situations the login-in check won't occur so that we can't make the authentication, and it just throw something like `Could not find a version`... And it seems that you use `pip install+pip.ini` to do the installation, for option1, only command with devops feed `--index-url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_packaging/xxx/pypi/simple/` is enough. Also, does it make any difference if we add the argument `--no-deps`, any update feel free to let me know:)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I didn't get anything like that, I just get the same `-vvv` log as with pip.ini as well. Is there any way to check whether artifacts-keyring is being triggered?

Comment: @NelsonYeung Hmm, it seems you're combining these two options(ways) that I never test before... See #3 in option1 and you can see `3. Follow the authentication flow in your browser.`. If you're actually using option1 way like me, you should see the sign-in log in command-line.  I test it in new machine with python 3.8, maybe it'll make a difference also? I'll try to configure a new machine with python 2.7 to reproduce the issue, it may take some time ...

Comment: In addition: for `check whether artifacts-keyring is being triggered`, trying uploading one new package in command-line twine with command `twine upload --repository-url`, if the publish is successful, it indicates the authentication is ok in your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The fix

Do one of the following:

- Remove the `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` environment variable (not very useful, not recommended).
- Add an extra `endpoint` to the `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` environment variable. E.g.,

```
{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/_packaging/NuGetFeed/nuget/v3/index.json", ...},{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/company_Software/_packaging/PyPI/pypi/simple/", ...}]}
```

We have a script which sets up these endpoints, so this turns out to be a simple fix.

## The cause

It turns out that if you have used [artifacts-credprovider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) to set up another feed, in our case, a NuGet feed with another endpoint, the `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` environment variable stores only that feed URL inside the key `endpoint`. [artifacts-keyring](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-keyring) will still read that environment variable even if the `endpoint` doesn't exist, which causes authentication problem. The `-vvv` log doesn't tell you anything about authentication and it won't attempt to authenticate using another method.

Comment: Hi Nelson, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members to search this useful information more easily, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 7):

> As a workaround:

Looks like you're using [option2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops#option-2-manually-configure-authentication) from [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops) to do the install. I happen to see one [similar issue](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000572308-Unable-to-install-PyPi-package) which indicates this error message could have something to do with `pip.ini`(windows) or `pip.conf`(linux/mac), so I think you can try another approach to avoid something wrong with those configurations.

You can run `pip install artifacts-keyring --pre` and then run

```
pip install packageName --index-url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_packaging/xxx/pypi/simple/ -vvv --no-deps
```

You would meet something like this when running command `pip install artifacts-keyring --pre`:

[image]

After the login-in passes, you would get the package you need if it do exist in your feed.

Comment: FYI: artifacts-keyring only works if you have dotnet installed. This is not automatically installed as a dependency when pip installing it.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your Azure DevOps artifacts is private and you have a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) then  installing a package from the artifact can be done in the following two ways

1. If you have access to a terminal (only preferred in dev environment)

```
pip install https://<your-feed-name>:<your-PAT-key>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<your-organization-name>/<your-project-name>/_packaging/<your-feed-name>/pypi/simple/ Your-Package-Name==x.x.x
```

**Note**: All the names (eg: feed, project) must follow the HTTPS URL convention.A simple (& actually correct) way to get to know the URL is goto Artifacts --> Select your artifact feed --> Connect to feed --> PIP --> Here you will get the correct URL. Also, use the some feed name both the place in URL

2. Using `requirements.txt` (this will be ideally used in prod or CI/CD pipeline) and automating the process:

Mind you it need a bit of string/URL manipulation. Add the respective line/URL in your `requirements.txt` in following manner:

- The URL will be mostly similar to the earlier URL used in the earlier terminal method
- In the URL after `simple` everything will have to change, modified URL-

```
https://<your-feed-name>:<your-PAT-key>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<your-organization-name>/<your-project-name>/_packaging/<your-feed-name>/pypi/download/<yourpackagename>/<package version>/Your-Package-Name.whl 
#assuming your package is a .whl file
```

- So `simple` changed to `download`; then whatever is your package name, whether it contains '-' or '_' or CAPS, everything will be removed and converted into small case.
- Next is version no of your package that you want to install & finally the name of wheel or `.whl` file.

Comment: As per @NaishOLoughlin the first method is almost correct, it should be: `pip install --extra-index-url=https://<your-feed-name>:<your-PAT-key>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<your-organization-name>/<your-project-name>/_packaging/<your-feed-name>/pypi/simple/ Your-Package-Name==x.x.x` otherwise it results in a 404

Comment: in my case URL was @microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/ instead of @pkgs.dev.azure.com/

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I had not installed artifacts-keyring. After that I could see VS Code authenticating to the feed and installing the package.

I also needed to upgrade pip (needs to be above > 19.2) with the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 2):

As an update to @user:10097045 's answer

You must add the --extra-index-url= infront of the URL with path in option 1 otherwise pip will fail to find the directory

Otherwise answer was super helpful you just get a 404 without that definition

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30874279)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this led me in the right direction. Looks like the proposed edit queue is full for that answer but I added a comment.