# pip package manager(python environments) inside visual studio 2019

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, pypi, python-packaging

I have put the .pypirc file in all the locations (project folder, C:\users\, in the root folders of all python environments) but still in Visual Studio 2019 when I click on [Manage Python Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKC9e.png)
as shown in the image, I do not find the Azure devops feed even though the azure devops feed is present in all the pypirc files as shown below. [python package sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRYvm.png). As seen it only list pypi and conda sources. Why doesn't it show the azure devops feed source.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't it show the azure devops feed source.

As I know VS itself doesn't have the option to support creating new package source like [what Nuget supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources). So something like `Packages(MyFeed)` in search box is not supported:

[image]

And I think that's why you can't see the feed source in UI. But it still supports searching packages in VS, you can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59465980/10910450) for more details about how to connect to the feed. If you're following [the document well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops#connect-to-your-feed) to connect to the feed, it will automatically try to search the package from PYPI and your custom feed:

[image]

[image]

Note: The `.pypirc` is used for Twine **upload** instead of Pip **install**.